# Read All Bytes Line By Line In .txt

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to read in all the bytes on one line only and throw them into an array, and then move onto the next line and so on and so forth.

For instance:

.txt File

```
word
apple
zzz
```

Now in my program I would have to read in the first line as a bunch of bytes, and my array would consist of 4 elements. I'd do my processing and move on to the next line and so on.

I have looked in many places but no luck. Ideally, I need something like `ReadAllBytes()` except instead of reading an entire file I need it to read only one line.

EDIT: Since I am going for speed, I cannot do ReadAllLines() or **anything** that would require me to read a string first and then convert it into an array of bytes.

EDIT2: I have to backtrack a bit now because I understand I am not the best at explaining anything, but I try. Ideally, this is how I would like the code to work

```
loop through all lines of txt file
    loop through all bytes on that line
        read the byte and process it
        if I need to, I break the loop and move on to the next line
```

This is just to give a better understand of my dilemma.

Even though the problem remains unsolved I'd still like to thank everyone that actually tried to help me: thank you for trying

Comment: bytes do not have "lines" the two concepts are incompatible. If you want to *convert* the string to bytes, thats totally possible however. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: What about `ReadLine()`?

Comment: Sorry I must have not been clear enough. I want to read all the bytes in a specific line of the txt and store them in a byte array. Bytes do not have lines, the txt has lines, but on each line is a varying number of bytes. e.x. the first line would result in a byte array with the values {119, 111, 114, 100}

Comment: @oopsidoodles I still don't get your problem. What is wrong with `ReadLine`

Comment: better start doing some reading / googling on how to read Lines from a text file.. please show more effort on your part please

Comment: `Since I am going for speed, I cannot do ReadAllLines()` who says reading it line by line will be faster? Your first problem is not speed, first you should have a working code.

Comment: You need at least some kind of line separator. When it is 0x0d (#13) then ReadLine will help you, unless if the data are bare bytes. In that case, you can need to use multiple calls to ReadByte(). You have {119, 111, 114, 100}. What comes after it so that {119, 111, 114, 100} is considered a line? {119, 111, 114, 100} is "word" so I still don't understand why `ReadLine` cannot help you.

Comment: I already have working code, but it is much too slow. I updated the question to show a quick run through of what I would need to do. I would simply loop through all the lines, then loop through all bytes on that line, and if need be, I break the loop and move on to the next line. This allows me to inspect every line in the txt and every byte on that line.

Comment: My other code was simple, it just did ReadAllLines() and that was that. I then process that array to get rid of all the strings I don't need. The method that I am trying to figure out would work much faster as I could inspect every single byte and if I don't like it, I don't add it and I stop on that line. @sjips the problem is that nothing comes after it so I have no idea when the line ends and a new line begins, this is why ReadAllBytes() does not work, which is why I need some way to look at the txt line by line and then look at each byte in that line.

Comment: `the problem is that nothing comes after it so I have no idea when the line ends and a new line begins, this is why ReadAllBytes() does not work` You mean: why ReadLine / ReadAllLines does not work?

Comment: ReadLine() and ReadAllLines() don't work because that way is too slow for my purposes.

Comment: Let me try to undertand it. This is your first assigment: `loop through all lines of txt file` and this is the second: `loop through all bytes on that line` but how can you accomplish these tasks if you don't know the line separator?

Comment: @oopsidoodles You still insist on not posting your code. I assume either there is none, or too embarrassing to post.

Comment: That's the problem. The txt I get is some random txt with a bunch of words in it. I was hoping there was some way to focus on a specific line. I mean, ReadAllLines() manages to somehow split up every line and store it in an array without line separators, I was hoping to do something similar. But yes, you understood it correctly.

Comment: @L.B. Since you want my current code, this is literally all I have in terms of reading the file: `dictionary = File.ReadAllLines("BigDictionary.txt").OfType<string>().ToList();`

Comment: @oopsidoodles as expected. You have nothing, and expect someone do your work for you and it is even not related with *speed*.

Comment: It is very much related to speed. My current way is very slow, and every other way I tried either doesn't work or isn't what I'm looking for. You wanted my current working code, and since I haven't been able to find a solution for the past hour+ this is all I have.

Comment: Hmmm, why not: `dictionary = File.ReadAllLines("BigDictionary.txt");`? `OfType<string>()` is redundant. You can iterate trough all the array items (ReadAllLines returns a string array); it is not more difficult than a list.

Comment: @oopsidoodles then you are on the wrong site. BTW: read http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem

Comment: @Sjips I actually need it to be a list, I can't have it an array because I constantly resize it afterwards, and I don't want to move everything down and index every time, hence the list.

Comment: @oopsidoodles Do you think noone here is capable of doing your homework? If you still don't get the answer you expect, then I would assume, it is because of your bad question.

Comment: @LB my problem seems to be like the third one. Many people have tried "try this" and I reply with "it won't work because of". The thing is that every single way that people have suggested actually does not work, which means the question remains unsolved. I came onto this website because I was stumped and didn't know what to do, so I asked the opinions of others. Since you are clearly not going to help me but rather judge and mock, so I kindly ask that you no longer post on this question unless you actually have an answer or something that would help.

Comment: @I4V my question was actually worded poorly in the start, and for that I apologize, but I have long since fixed it and I know that it is understandable because Sjips understood the problem perfectly.

Comment: @oopsidoodles But I am here, and will continue to post my comments till you read what to ask and how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: I think: try to get it working. If it is too slow, use a profiler to find the bottleneck. Then come back to SO, post the code and your findings, and ask how it can be optimized. You see that a lot of people want to help you, but are not understanding what you really want.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your text file is ASCII:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\foo.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
    // do some processing with byte array
}
```

**Updated** to `ReadLines()` based on comments.

Comment: I made an edit because of this, but I cannot read in all the lines first, as I am going for speed, and that would take too long, but thanks for trying.

Comment: @oopsidoodles: You can use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines`, then the lines will be read as you iterate them.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **StreamReader.ReadLine** to read a single line from a specific file then convert the string to an array of bytes and finally do you job.

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line))
                {
                    //do your work here 
                    //break the foreach loop if the condition is not satisfied
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read *SomeEncoding.GetBytes*  method... Encodings like UTF8 have variable length bytes.

Comment: i didn't use the method GetBytes from the encoding class because i don't know the current file encoding. and to make it general.

Comment: You don't know the encoding but you use `File.OpenText` assuming text file is in ASCII or UTF8 :)

Comment: This is probably as close as it's going to get, thank you. I realize that there probably is no way to do exactly what I need, which is alright, and this is probably as close as it is going to get, so thank you. If I could vote up, I would, but I don't have enough rep :C